# Bad class String while converting currency to Double

Tags: java, android, string-formatting

**Here is my code:**

```
  private double stripCurrency(String sBudget) {

    DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setCurrencySymbol("");
    formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
    double d = Double.valueOf(formatter.format(sBudget)); // Line 52 in LogCat
    return d;
  }
```

**Here is LogCat:**

```
09-16 10:12:07.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1463):     at java.text.NumberFormat.format(NumberFormat.java:304)
09-16 10:12:07.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1463):     at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:702)
09-16 10:12:07.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1463):     at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
09-16 10:12:07.641: E/AndroidRuntime(1463):     at com.---.---.GasUtil.stripCurrency(GasUtil.java:52)
```

This happens when opening app for the first time. The passed in String is the `SharedPreference` default of "100".

**What I am trying to do:**

There should be a `String` stored in `SharedPreferences` and I convert that to a double.  An older version of the app allowed for currency symbols in the String.  So I am trying to sanitize from that old way. So I am formatting it to strip out old currency symbols and turning into a double.  Not sure if my above code is the best way to do that, even after I resolve this bug, or if there is a better way?  So I need to sanitize in a way that will handle both correct and bad formatting.

Comment: is the currency symbol known before hande? is the value stored in the String always a double, but sometimes with a '$'? like would "4.00","$4.00","$1.00" all be possible valid values?

Comment: Just don't remove the currency symbol from the format. Why did you do it in the first place? Were you worried that a "$" would creep into a `double`?

Comment: @Ordous  I use the variable in calculations.  So I decided to ONLY show currency when an item is about to be displayed.  @Dave It could be 100, 100.00 or $100.  I simply want to take either one and covert it to a `double` (or `BigDecimal` -- but these are basic, basic calculations).

Comment: @KickingLettuce That doesn't answer my question. Why did you remove the currency symbol from the `DecimalFormat` object? Your output won't have the currency sign anyway *since it's a `double`, not a `String`*

Comment: I thought it was a good way to strip out any currency sign so it formats safely from string to double.  I got the idea from another question here.

Comment: [Dont use `double` for currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`formatter.format(sBudget)` does take an Object, but it checks if it is any form of a `Number` otherwise it throws `IllegalArgumentException`. Look at the source code `DecimalFormat`.

Here is the corrected way of converting a currency string back to double.

```
private static double stripCurrency(String sBudget) {
        //to handle strings with no dollar sign.
        if(sBudget.trim().charAt(0) != '$') {
            sBudget = "$"+sBudget;
        }
        DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
        Number parse = null;
        try {
            parse = formatter.parse(sBudget);
            System.out.println(parse);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return parse.doubleValue();
    }
```

Here is the source code for the root cause of the exception you are facing. When we call `formatter.format(sBudget)`, the call end up with the following method in `DecimalForamt`.

```
public final StringBuffer format(Object number,
                                     StringBuffer toAppendTo,
                                     FieldPosition pos) {
        if (number instanceof Long || number instanceof Integer ||
                   number instanceof Short || number instanceof Byte ||
                   number instanceof AtomicInteger ||
                   number instanceof AtomicLong ||
                   (number instanceof BigInteger &&
                    ((BigInteger)number).bitLength () < 64)) {
            return format(((Number)number).longValue(), toAppendTo, pos);
        } else if (number instanceof BigDecimal) {
            return format((BigDecimal)number, toAppendTo, pos);
        } else if (number instanceof BigInteger) {
            return format((BigInteger)number, toAppendTo, pos);
        } else if (number instanceof Number) {
            return format(((Number)number).doubleValue(), toAppendTo, pos);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot format given Object as a Number");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!  I actually dealt with this in the past and used `Number`.  Marking as correct.

Comment: Ok, I ran into one issue first; and I had a feeling this would happen. `Unparseable number "100.00"`.  I remember `Number` failing if it was NOT a currency and it just did that.  I need in my code, to work if it is currency for not.  As I mentioned above, the number being passed in, may look like `100.00` or `$100.`

Comment: I see the problem, I thought you always have `$`. One dirty work around would be adding `$` at the beginning if one is not there.

Comment: Is it possible to do a type check? Check if String can be converted to Double, if not, convert it to number first?

Comment: We can do that by `try { Double.parseDouble(sBudget);} catch(NumberFormatException e) { }` catching the `NumberFormatException`. If it throws NumberFormatException, you are sure that the string can not format because of having some alphabetics or null

Comment: I tried your last suggestion and it seems to work fine!